# Mouse scroll and trackpad behaving differently

Tags: terminal, keyboard, mouse, trackpad, vi

I am using a dell mouse with my mac. Although in most context scrolling the mouse wheel produces the same effect as swiping down with two fingers, it sometimes happen that the mouse does not work. One example is with vim (terminal).

I press the shift key and scroll: nothing happens. I press the shift key and swipe down and the page shifts.

**EDIT**

I tried with Better touch tool but it is of no help.

Answer (score 2):

Shift/scrollwheel is *horizontal* scroll, which will only work, of course, if there is somewhere to scroll to horizontally.

I've never used a trackpad, but I presume horizontal scroll on a trackpad can be quite specifically indicated by horizontal movement - it can't, of course, on a mouse-wheel.

As noted in comments by [timothymh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/12285/timothymh), [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) ($20) can override this behaviour & set Page Up/Page Down to the shift/scroll action.

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly the cause of your problem. You may be able to override this with a tool such as SteerMouse.

Comment: @timothymh - good call - Added to answer.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have already purchased external software to trying to do that. It's called better touch tool. Unsuccessful trial. I am not very inclined on buying another one...

Comment: Yes, it would have been better to mention it in the question - also what about it was unsatisfactory... as I just went to the effort of making SteerMouse do exactly what you requested :/

Comment: Downloaded trial version of SteerMouse. Does not work. What it does is to replicate the behaviour of the keyboard down up and down keys. The trackpad is different. Please try with the example I suggested (vim on a terminal).

Comment: I don't have a trackpad or vim.